# Scheduling a job

Tags: apex, scheduled-apex

I have a

class

and another class that implements schedulable that calls the first class.

I am pushing an update to production to the class.

Do I need to unschedule the job then reschedule it?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you go to Setup > Deployment Settings and check "Allow deployments of components when corresponding Apex jobs are pending or in progress.
Caution: Enabling this option may cause Apex jobs to fail.", you'll be allowed to deploy those changes without unscheduling the job first. Note that this *may* cause undesirable behavior, and it is *recommended* that you unschedule the jobs first to avoid any potential issues.

Comment: Thanks!!! I'll unschedule then reschedule, i'll accept your answer once timer allows